# Eclipse not working when VPN is enabled

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, vpn, pia

Eclipse can't access remote resources when I have VPN enabled.

I use PIA's VPN (https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/), I asked them but they say they don't provide support for Eclipse.

When I try to import a Gradle project it fails with the following error:

Permission denied: connect

Any idea of how to make Eclipse work when a VPN is on?

Comment: depending on the VPN, you may need to use a proxy or open a SSH tunnel and use a different port. Talk with your sysadmin

Comment: The problem is that there is no sysadmin to contact, I'm using a personal VPN solution, I run the program on my computer and all my traffic is supposed to be routed over the VPN connection.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you want to access some remote resources they need to accessible by the network you are using.

your VPN might not know how to reach that resource.
you can add exception routes in command prompt to ask your VPN to explicitly go to that path and provide ipaddres of your remote resource there.

you might need to contact your system administrator to configure it for you

Comment: As I mentioned on the question, I'm using a personal VPN solution, I run the program on my computer and all my traffic is supposed to be routed over the VPN connection. I'm not sure at what level of the network stack this is done, but I can see all my browser's traffic, Skype traffic and torrent's traffic is routed over the VPN.

Comment: Also, if I try to access the same URLs for which Eclipse throws an error directly on the web browser I can access them without trouble, so it seems like there is some sort of problem in the way eclipse handles the connections.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50753156/1707589) did the trick.

Under `Preferences...` -> `General` -> `Network Connections`
Change `Active Provider` to `Native`.