# Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Cannot resolve host

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I am using eclipse Kepler version and trying to install Sonar plugin from Eclipse marketplace.
But I am getting below error

> Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace Cannot install remote marketplace
>   locations: Cannot resolve host
>
> This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection.
>   Please check your internet connection and retry. Unknown Host:
>   http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p marketplace.eclipse.org
>   Cannot resolve host
>
> This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection.
>   Please check your internet connection and retry.
>   marketplace.eclipse.org

I tried below things as per solution suggested by some people.

1. Go to Window-> Preferences -> General -> Network Connection. And
   change below settings Active Provider-> Manual-> and check---> HTTP,
   HTTPS and SOCS. After restarting eclipse still the problem persisted.
2. I tried connecting to google.com from Eclipse Internet Explorer and able to see google homepage
3. Added line in eclipse.ini file
   **-vmargs
   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true** But still same issue

I am really frustated by this issue and couldn't find any help anywhere. If anyone has faced this issue and has an effective resolution, please assist.

Below is the snap of Proxy details
[image]

Comment: I am also struggling after trying all the provided solutions without success.

Answer (score 33):

The solution is:

1. Go to-Window->Preferences->General->Network Connections
2. Choose "Active Provider" To "Direct"
3. then click "apply" and then "ok".

It will Start Opening.

Answer (score 10):

I tried all the suggestions but no success for Eclipse Mars, Neo and Oxygen
At last it worked for Eclipse Oxygen when I added following line to eclipse.ini file

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: After trying all other options,this did the trick for me on Windows 10.

Comment: FYI, it must be added next to `vmarg` in eclipse.ini file.

Answer (score 9):

- Go to: Window->Preferences->General->Network Connections
- Choose "Active Provider" To "Native"
- Click 'apply' and then 'Ok'

NOTE: I gone through all possibilities 
      - marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api* (Not Working)
      - change 'Active Provider' to 'Manual'/'Direct'(Not Working)
      - Disable Proxies entries/Bypass(Not Working)

Answer (score 6):

Try to add the host like this: `marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api*` in Proxy bypass.

[image]

Comment: these should be checked, right? and for me its not working in any case. on CentOS 7

Answer (score 5):

1. Open command prompt (windows start button, type cmd in search)
2. Click top left of command prompt, click properties, enable quick edit mode
3. Copy: setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
4. Right click on command prompt, should paste
5. Hit enter. That easy!

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse Oxygen version: Window->Preferences->network connections->default apply will reset the settings. restart eclipse and it should work

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the suggestions but no success for Eclipse Neon and Oxygen. At last it worked for Eclipse Neon when I added below line in Configuration Settings in eclipse folder.

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Edit Configuration Settings in eclipse folder and add the below line and save it.
It will work.

Comment: Adding this entry in eclipse.ini file worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For me I solved the problem by those steps:

1. Use the CNTLM proxy, which can be installed and run by following [this GitHub readme file](https://gist.github.com/triskell/2b0922a2469a448b507b).
2. Go to-Window->Preferences->General->Network Connections
3. Click on an empty line and add a host and the same port that youn configured in CNTLM

[image: Eclipse CNTLM Proxy]

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue and here is how I solved it.

I didn't find any other similar answers that work for me, so here it is:

Go to : **Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections**

[image: Network Connections]

- Put the **Active Provider** to **Manual**.
- Add the correct **Host** and **Port** for all Proxy entries.
- Click on the line with **SOCKS** and click on **Clear** on the right.
- Delete all lines in **Proxy bypass** and add a line with **localhost**.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running behind a NTLM proxy? If so you might find help at [this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338212/eclipse-kepler-not-connecting-to-internet-via-proxy)

A bit hacky workaround would be to download the plugins manually and than add it via 'Add local update site'.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I solved it with following steps:

- Window -> Preferences -> Secure Storage
- Tab - Contents
- Delete [Default Secure Storage]
- Restart Eclipse

Don't worry - Storage will be re-created automatically.

Comment: Didnt understand why, but This worked for me! Thank you

Comment: it didn't worked for me either. I tried Eclipse Mars / Oxygen / Neo

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the possible suggestions given above but finally got answer for this :
This may not be the right way to install the plugin but it worked for me and it served my purpose

Open the below URL :
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=252148

Open eclipse and drag the plugin from the above url drop on eclipse [on top near header]

It will start downloading and eclipse will restart after successful installation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestion above with Eclipse Photon. None worked. Finally got the marketplace to open by installing Eclipse to a path with no white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

when launching, java application defaults to listening to ipv6 exclusively. Modify .ini configuration settings file present in the folder by adding -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true below the -vmargs.
This sets the java to prefer IPV4 stack.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you have any proxy connection set in your network settings. You can check that in your Proxy Settings in Windows.

Just copy the proxy host from there and add it in Proxy Bypass Host list inside

- Window->Preferences->General->Network Connections
- Then click on Apply & CLose.

It should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same today morning on `Ubuntu 20.04LTS` with `Eclipse Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)`. This is what worked for me.

```
sudo vim /etc/resolve.conf
```

And add these 2 lines.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Save the file and restart the network. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when I was connected to VPN. But It worked after I disconnected my VPN.

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind corporate firewall, You could try adding these two lines at the end of your eclipse.ini:

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NONE

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1113326&goto=1860034&#msg_1860034